# Array passing and returning

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering.. Whenever I deal with arrays, when I have to cut it, or sort it, or anything, and then return it, I pass it to the void function like `f(array, length, newarray)` and in the function declaration I have void `f(T *array, int length, T *&new array)`.
Is there a better way to do this?

Here's some code, I want to remove repeats from an array:

```
template<class T>
void eliminate(T *niz, int duzina, T *&podniz)
{
    int ind;
    podniz = new T[duzina];
    for (int i = 0; i<duzina; i++)
    {
        ind = 0;
        for (int j = i; j<duzina; j++)
        {
            if (niz[i] == niz[j])ind++;
        }
        if (ind == 1)podniz[nova++] = niz[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the function returning the new array? Something like `T* f(T* array, int length);`

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Yes, there is. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: This question is too broad. Returning a new array is "functionally" better.

Comment: @Ron: Cutting elements from a `std::array` is a bit tricky, though ;)

Comment: @MSalters I've added some code..

Comment: @MSalters Indeed, I missed that one on the first reading.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the comments, you really want `std::vector`.

The main problem with your code is that there is no way to tell how many of the output elements are actually initialized. And accessing uninitialized elements is Undefined Behavior, so you are returning a time bomb to the caller.

With `std::vector<T> eliminate(std::vector const&)`, there's no such doubt. The returned vector has exactly `.size()` elements.

Vector is also exception-safe. Your code will leak memory if the copy constructor of `T` throws, e.g. on a `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: I have a global variable to count the number of elements, as you see it's not initialized in the function itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to std::vector as soon as I finish the course where we learn to code std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use pointers and pass the array by reference to the function.
Then manipulate the array and return from the function with void type i.e no need of returning the array as it is passed by reference.

Comment: In C++, passing an array by reference means something different than passing a pointer.